# Branch, tag or something else in SVN to indicate overriden functionality?

Tags: svn

I am writing first project with SVN (Java + frameworks + HTML).  So far only commits, and sometimes update to recent version. I want to change some functionality which works already in my project (this touches several files), and maybe in the future I would like to undo what is done now (if I or customer decided to choose previous implementation/layout of functionality).

How can I achieve this? Something like two versions of functionality in one svn project.

Answer (score 3):

If you plan this as a kind of "experimental feature", then you could create a branch for that feature. If you later decide to ignore it, just leave the branch, if you decide to make it the "main" branch, merge it back to your trunk.

If, however, this is a "real" feature and you simply want to remember what the old code looked like than a tag (`pre_huge_change_bug1234`) might be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are modifying the functionality i would opt for a branch. 
And have 2 branches of the same project.